# Java Get Generic Type without extends

Tags: java, hibernate, generics

I have a simple interface like this.

```
public interface EntityClass
{    
   public void setId(final Integer id);    
   public Integer getId();    
}
```

and a class

```
public Student implements EntityClass{}
```

But this code is giving me error i want to know the `Generic Type`

```
public class MyGenericType<T extends EntityClass>
{
     private final Class<? extends EntityClass>genericClazz;
     public MyGenericType()
     {   
        genericClazz=(Class<? extends EntityClass>)((ParameterizedType)getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        return;
     }        
 }
```

Later i try this code like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{        
     final MyGenericType<Student>action = new MyGenericType<>();
}
```

But it throws

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType
```

This code i been using it but extending from subclass but i dont want to my `GenericType` extending from any class.

What can i do to be able to get the `Student` type from this code.

```
final MyGenericType<Student>action = new MyGenericType<>();
```

Because i need to get a `Hibernate namedQuery.`

Comment: The only way to capture generic type information at runtime is via an `extends` statement. Any other type information is erased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get information about the generic type because of *erasure*, which, in short, means that the Java compiler doesn't keep generic type information about the actual instance in the generated byte code.

However, the compiler does not remove generic type information of the **superclass** of the actual instance. So you can use `(ParameterizedType) this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()` on a **descendant** of the class that has a generic type parameter, and, for that, you need to use the `extends` keyword:

```
public interface EntityClass {
    public void setId(final Integer id);

    public Integer getId();
}

public class Student
    implements EntityClass {

    // getters and setters
}

public abstract class MyGenericType<T extends EntityClass> {

    private final Class<T> genericClazz;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public MyGenericType() {
        this.genericClazz = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass())
            .getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    protected Class<T> getGenericClazz() {
        return this.genericClazz;
    }

}

public class MyStudentType // no way to avoid extending a generic type
    extends MyGenericType<Student> {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.getGenericClazz().getSimpleName();
    }
}

public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final MyStudentType action = new MyStudentType();
        System.out.println(action); // Student
    }
}
```

One comment regarding this cast within `MyGenericType<T>` class' constructor:

```
genericClazz = (Class<? extends EntityClass>)...
```

Since `T` is declared to extend from `EntityClass`, you don't need to use wildcards. Using just `T` would suffice:

```
genericClazz = (Class<T>)...
```

Regarding the `ClassCastException` you're getting, that's because in your example, `MyGenericType` doesn't have a generic superclass (actually, it doesn't have any superclass, except for `Object`, which is not a `ParameterizedType`. So, when you use this cast: `(ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()`, you're getting a `ClassCastException`.

---

**EDIT:**

I forgot you were asking how to do this **without** having to extend from any class. One way is to pass the generic type in the constructor:

```
public class MyGenericType<T extends EntityClass> {

    private final Class<T> genericClazz;

    public MyGenericType(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.genericClazz = clazz;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.genericClazz.getSimpleName();
    }
}
```

And then:

```
public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final MyGenericType<Student> action = new MyGenericType<>(Student.class);
        System.out.println(action); // Student
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

Another way is to make your `MyGenericType` class `abstract` and let subclasses return the generic type. This might be enforced by generics, so that if a subclass attempts to return the wrong type, it gets a compilation error:

```
public abstract class MyGenericType<T extends EntityClass> {

    protected abstract Class<T> getGenericType();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.getGenericType().getSimpleName();
    }
}

public class MyStudentType 
    extends MyGenericType<Student> {

    @Override
    protected Class<Student> getGenericType() {
        return Student.class;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final MyStudentType action = new MyStudentType();
        System.out.println(action); // Student
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) There is no such thing as not inheriting from any class, every thing is an extension of the Object class, so even if you don't specify anything, by default it will extend Object.

2) There are 2 ways to get the runtime type in the generic class, you can use getClass on a variable, or pass in the class in the constructor or method.
Sample code:

Method 1 (Preferred if possible):

```
public class MyGenericType<T extends EntityClass>
{
     public <T extends EntityClass> void someMethod(final T someVar)
     {   
         Class c = someVar.getClass();
     }        
 }
```

Method 2 (if you need to determine at construction time, this is the only way):

```
public class MyGenericType<T extends EntityClass>
{
     private final Class<? extends EntityClass>genericClazz;
     public MyGenericType(Class t)
     {   
         genericClazz = t;
         return;
     }        
 }
```